# How do I cancel Ubuntu One Music Streaming?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I need to cancel my Ubuntu One Music Streaming.

I do not know what web site address to use.

My cell phone will not download this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to view your current subscriptions on the Ubuntu One web site at:

https://one.ubuntu.com/account/

If you click the `See Details` button next to the subscription you're interested in, there should be a `Cancel this subscription` button on the page you get sent to.

If this doesn't help, I suggest you send a support request through the web form:

https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/